# Create empty SQL Table with customize insert a list to create a column

Tags: sql, isqlquery

I want to create #1 table In which I want insert customer ids

```
('123t','23x4','4g56','5k67',.....)
```

Customer id can be of any length.

This is the code I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #1 
(
    CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #1 (id) 
VALUES ('123t', '23x4', '4g56', '5k67', '5k07', '1g36', '21x4')

SELECT * FROM #1
```

Expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: ```#1``` is not a valid SQL. It seems that it is customer table so change to ```CREATE TABLE Customer (..)```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Anything not working with the given code? Are you facing any error message? Which database system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert values into a column named `id`, but your table has a column named `CUSTOMER_ID`. Also, you mentioned that the customer IDs can be of any length, so you should use `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
    CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(MAX)
);

-- Insert customer IDs into the table
INSERT INTO #YourTable  (CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES 
('123t'), ('23x4'), ('4g56'), ('5k67'), 
('5k07'), ('1g36'), ('21x4');

-- Select all rows from the table
SELECT * FROM #YourTable ;
```

Comment: I am getting error of "The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values".

Comment: SQL server you are using has a limit on the number of row values that can be inserted in a single `INSERT` statement, and that is 1000 by default. You can break the `INSERT` statement into multiple smaller batches to work around the limitation.

Comment: i have more then 1 lakhs customer_id , i have to do 100 times ? that's not possible

Comment: Where do you (currently) keep these values? In a file? If so, can't you **import** them into the table?

Comment: Where have you keep these `customer_id`, in CVS file or in another table?

Comment: its in csv , i copy those customer id paste in the sql . i know ideally we should upload .but i dont have the right to upload . can we write in store procedure

Comment: Stored procedures have database-specific syntactical quirks so we would need to know what database you were using before we could give you any advice on writing one. Will writing a stored procedure gain you anything? It sounds like you could use a stored procedure that inserts a single row. You could then write a script to convert a CSV file to a lengthy collection of individual calls to that stored procedure. How does the time to do this compare with the time required to get bulk upload permission?